# Load Balancing ignores half my node count when using Firefox

Tags: networking, load-balancing, digital-ocean, devops, traefik

I've tried two different load balancing setups and I've seen the same results no matter which technology I use, so there must be something I'm missing.

- Digital Ocean Load Balancer to Droplets
- Traefik Load Balancer to Containers

In both cases, when I try to load balance to an even number of containers or droplets, it ignores half. So for example:

- 1 node, Load balancing send traffic to 1.
- 2 nodes, Load balancing send traffic to 1.
- 3 nodes, Load balancing send traffic to 3.
- 4 nodes, Load balancing send traffic to 2.

I did a screen capture video from my setup on Digital Ocean that you can view to see the behavior:
https://youtu.be/EP_eOtuPGLs

As you can see, when I have 2 droplets it only send traffic to 1. When I add a third droplet it sends traffic to 3. Note that I'm seeing the same behavior in Traefik as well, so its probably not specific to either technology, but just something I'm missing with Load Balancing in general.

Comment: the "hello from" seems to change as you reload, which would mean load balancing is actually working (assuming what you're displaying is the server signature along with the "hello from"). Can you share the config of your DO load balancer? (not the member droplets, but the balancing configuration)... it seems odd that when using 2 droplets if sticks to only one

Comment: As you see. It does not change when 2 nodes are up. But when I add a third node it does. That’s my issue. Works fine with 3, doesn’t work at all with 2.

Comment: yup, premature "enter" in the previous comment... added " it seems odd that when using 2 droplets if sticks to only one" as you were typing :)

Comment: Yes, also as I write in the post. When I add 4 it balances between 2. So seems like even numbers ignore half.

Comment: that's incredibly weird... My current setup in DO uses 2 droplets behind a standard load balancer and it works as expected (just checked, hehe)... any chance we can see the LB configuration?

Comment: After further testing, it seems to be related to which browser I'm using. On Chrome it load balances between both, on Mozilla Firefox (my default browser) it's having these issues. I've disabled all extensions but still seem to be occuring.

Comment: Do you have sticky sessions enabled?

Comment: No. Sticky Sessions is off and Healthchecks are done with TCP port 22. That’s the only configuration set.

Comment: I'm puzzled... have you tried getting in touch with DO's support? I just changed my setup to your exact configuration (checks on TCP 22, no sticky sessions, round robin) and it works as it should with both even and odd droplet numbers. Have you tried nuking that LB and creating a new one?

Comment: Yes I’m in touch with DO. They have reset the LB, I’ve also destroyed and rebuild my entire environment with Terraform. Probably there’s something on my side that is the issue. I’ve tried on 2 computers, using 2 vpn and my normal ISP, all results in the same issue when using Firefox. I’ve also compared request headers between Chrome and Firefox and I can’t find anything weird. Very confusing.

Comment: Solved it. See answer @JavierLarroulet

Comment: Unbelievable, I would have NEVER guessed that! Great that you figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing I noticed that the issue was restricted to using Firefox. When doing CURL or Chrome requests it was returning the correct response.

After comparing the requests in Firefox and  Chrome I realized that Firefox always sends an extra HTTP request to fetch a favicon -- no matter if the HTML defines one or not.

This means that every time I visited my load balancer in Firefox, it was actually sending 2 requests. So the web request went to Droplet A and the Favicon request went to Droplet B. When I refresh the page, due to even load balancing the web request again went to Droplet A. So I was never able to see any response from Droplet B.

So to summarize, there never was an issue with the load balancers. It was just my testing method using Firefox that was flawed.